# Responsibility of the Service Layer and Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, repository, service-layer

I need some advice on where to draw the line with my services and repositories.

```
public class Contact
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Username {get;set;}
     public Guid? AvatarId {get;set;}
     public Avatar Avatar {get;set;}
}

public class Avatar
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string FullSizeImagePath {get;set;}
     public string ThumbnailSizeImagePath {get;set;}
}
```

Let's assume the Avatar model will only be used on a Contact model and that it is an optional property on the Contact. Should my repository be responsible for adding an Avatar to the contact or should the business / service layer extend that functionality? One can argue that it is a business requirement to have an avatar, but since it is part of the model the data layer should know how to deal with it.

I proposed we could add the functionality to Add / Update and Remove an avatar via the repository. The Business / Service layer would be responsible for saving the physical files, validation, and calling the appropriate methods on the repository. All the repository cares about is attaching the appropriate contact and adding an avatar to it.

my thought process was that since an avatar is only being used on a Contact, currently, we would extend the repository and thus add functionality to the DAL. This might be useful for a separate API.

Comment: Offtop, why you need `AvatarId` property in `Contact` class since you can access it as `Avatar.Id`?

Comment: @sll I think thats required by entity framework (code first) to assist in defining the navigation property Avatar

Comment: @sll: I use it for navigation and mapping for entity framework. I can tell EF that avatar can be null-able in the database.

Comment: @MikeHanrahan It's definitely not required by EF. The relationship can be mapped just by using `Avatar`.

Comment: @Yuck, while it is not required, it does allow you to specify null values in your mappings for that entity.

Comment: @DDiVita `Avatar` itself can be `null`, which the EF will map to `NULL` in the database. You don't need the repeated key property. You just have to tell EF how to map the keys.

Comment: @Yuck, are you sure? in the past if I did not set the key property to be null-able, I would get an error on insert, from EF there is a FK relationship error, unless I physically went into the database and set the Avatar_Id (generated by EF if I did not specify a FK in the mappings) to be allow null. I think the same goes for not setting the key to be null-able in code first. So if I do not set the Guid to be null-able I should get the same constraint error.

Comment: @DDiVita Trough your mappings you can specify that Avatar is nullable. You don't need the nullable id for this. However, Foreign Key properties are really useful in EF. They allow you to select or change the id of a relationship without loading the whole navigational property. So setting Contact.AvatarId to the id of another Avatar and saving it to the database will change the whole relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I would not add this to your repositories but define it in your business layer.

If you follow Domain Driven Design, your `Contact` would get an `AddAvatar` method that would be responsible for creating the `Avatar` and setting the correct properties.

Repositories are only created for aggregate roots. As you already state that `Avatar` is only accessible trough your `Contact`, your data layer should not contain an `AvatarRepository`. You can load the `Avatar` trough the corresponding contact.

You also state that the BLL would be responsible for saving the physical file. I would think this trough for a moment.Do you really want code that's dealing with physical files in your BLL?

Let's say you move your Avatar files to your database for scaling and backup reasons, that code would suddenly move to a Repository. 
A Repository is something we map immediately to a database in our thought process but is is a generic term for a data store, it can also store physical files. We don't mind how the Repository implements this. Al we care about is writing our business logic with business problems and not worrying about infrastructure issues.

So I would move the code for creating and updating your `Avatar` to your BLL and the code for dealing with the physical file to your `Repository`.

Comment: I never really thought about physical files going through a repository. Makes perfect sense! Old habits I suppose.

Comment: Storing files is a part of your infrastructure But indeed, old habits :-)